# Windows client to monitor remote unix server using ssh

Tags: unix, ssh, system, monitoring

Is there a program that would connect to a remote unix server using ssh, and show various system info (CPU usage, Memory usage, disk space..etc) ?
I should mention that I'm using windows, and I have non-root access via ssh to the machine that I want to monitor. Also, I can't use any web-based tools, because the server is only accessible from my work computer, using site-to-site VPN.
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest thing I found is an android app that connects to a linux server via ssh, and shows some system info.
Here it is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh.performancemonitor
It is a plugin for JuiceSSH ssh client so you need to install that first.

Comment: wow I actually lost points more than 2 years after I posted this question ! :D care to explain the downvote ?